# How to connect 2 MSSQL queriues with c#?

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-2.0

I have following question - I need to build category list from unique department name and under each department list articles, which belongs to it.

I wrote 2 mssql queries:
1) Selecting unique department's name (table consists of id and string name):

```
select distinct (fs.ob_no), fs.c_name as fs_c_name from et_filials_suggest fs order by fs.ob_no
```

and getting something like this:

```
ob_no     fs_c_name
244400  IT Department
244401    HR Department
```

2) Than I select articles:

```
select              s.ob_no as s_ob_no,
                s.c_name as s_c_name,
                s.e_fio,
                s.e_text_header,
                s.e_datetime,
                s.e_link_filial,
                fs.c_name
                from et_suggest s
                inner join et_filials_suggest fs on fs.ob_no = s.e_link_filial
                where s.c_visible=1 
                AND s.e_lean_flag=1 
                AND fs.c_visible=1
```

and getting something like this:

```
s.ob_no |   s.c_name       | s.e_fio | s.e_text_header | s.e_datetime            |s.e_link_filial | fs.c_name
458713  |   Article_sys_name | Me      |Aricle_vis_name  | 2013-11-12 00:00:00.000 |44410           | IT deparment
```

And here goes the problem, I don't understand how to make list, e.g.:

**IT Department**

- Article 1
- Article 2

**HR Department**

- Article 3

....

Here I get list of departments:

**<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fs_c_name")%>**

But how can I connect it with articles? Seems to me that I should set variable in first query but how can I use it later?

Here is the full example of code I've made - article is limited to 1 and it displays under each department without connection to it:

```
<mso:Query ID="Query1" runat="server" CommandType="Text" CommandText="select distinct (fs.ob_no), fs.c_name as fs_c_name from et_filials_suggest fs order by fs.ob_no">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <b><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fs_c_name")%></b><br />
                <mso:Query ID="Query1" runat="server" CommandType="Text" CommandText="
                select top (1)
                s.ob_no as s_ob_no,
                s.c_name as s_c_name,
                s.e_fio,
                s.e_text_header,
                s.e_datetime,
                s.e_link_filial,
                fs.c_name
                from et_suggest s
                inner join et_filials_suggest fs on fs.ob_no = s.e_link_filial
                where s.c_visible=1 
                AND s.e_lean_flag=1 
                AND fs.c_visible=1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="/magazine.aspx?CatalogId=458560&d_no=<%#DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "s_ob_no") %>"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "s_c_name")%></a><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </mso:Query>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </mso:Query>
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

**UPDATE:**

Well i have an idea - if i change in 2nd query inner join to left join and add where clause i can get list of articles for department:

```
select 
                s.ob_no as s_ob_no,
                s.c_name as s_c_name,
                s.e_fio,
                s.e_text_header,
                s.e_datetime,
                s.e_link_filial,
                fs.c_name
                from et_suggest s
                left join et_filials_suggest fs on fs.ob_no = s.e_link_filial
                where s.c_visible=1 
                AND s.e_lean_flag=1 
                AND fs.c_visible=1
                AND s.e_link_filial=244411
```

But i still don't know how to change number from:

```
AND s.e_link_filial=244411
```

to variable from the first query:

```
select distinct (fs.ob_no), fs.c_name as fs_c_name from et_filials_suggest fs order by fs.ob_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
AND s.e_link_filial=244411
```

and all records will be returned

you should instead add the following line

```
ORDER BY s.e_link_filial=244411
```

*By the way, in web page development, while binding grid view with this type of information, I use a different approach.
Let me know if you are interested to know, I will update my answer.*